# Using Google Scripts to upload without intervention

Tags: google-apps-script

I have used the below to upload files from my local drive by choosing a file from the UI.  I would like to upload a particular file with a static pathway every day.  Is there a way to have a script upload a particular file? (Then I could just use triggers to make sure it happened routinely).

```
function doGet(e) {

 var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Upload CSV to Sheet");
   var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
   formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
   formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton());
   var form = app.createFormPanel();
   form.add(formContent);
   app.add(form);
   return app;
 }

 function doPost(e) {
   // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
   var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
   var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
 }'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is **not** possible (using Apps Script). Apps Script runs on Google servers and therefore do not have access to your local files.

I wrote an [article for Steegle](http://www.steegle.com/google-products/google-apps-script-faq) a while ago where I explain such Apps Script's aspects. You might want to give it a quick read.

You have to write such program using "traditional" development tools. That is, programs that run in your computer. For example, a Java program using Google Drive API [library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2) could do this easily. Then you could schedule it using your OS's scheduling feature (e.g. cron on linux/unix).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  In this case, let me ask this:  in the above script, once navigates to the files to upload manually and submits.  The, the "doPost" takes over, utilizing the selected path.  Is there a way to hard-code, what doPost uses?  Seems like this would be a work-around here.  Thoughts?

Comment: Due to security concerns, the browser never informs any page ot the "path" of any file. It just informs the file, it's name and mimetype. It's not possible to workaround here. Specially within `doPost` which is already on server-side. But not even in the client-side, regardless if it's Apps Script or any other custom page you have there.